# Git codebase repo to live site

Tags: git, codebase

So created a website on my localhost. And I pushed to codebase, and I want push it to live, how do I do that?

here is my order:

```
1. $ git init (setup on my local)
2. $ git add .
3. $ git commit -m 'initial commit'
4. $ git remote add origin git@codebasehq.com:yourcodebasedomain/yourproject/example.git
5. $ git push origin master (pushes to codebase)
6. ??? - How do I push my codebase repo to live site?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather an involved process, as you need to set up a Git hook to be able to push directly to the server. I recommend the tutorial at http://sebduggan.com/blog/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/

Answer (score 0):

Codebase supports [post-receive hooks](http://support.codebasehq.com/articles/repositories/post-receive-hooks), in that it will generates a JSON payload to the url of your choice.

If that url is your live site server, that server can listen to it, and upon reception, cal **pull from the codebase repo**.

In other words, repo hosting services (GitHub, BitBucket, codebase, ...) cannot push directly.
But they can signal to other servers (like your live site server) that a push just occurred.